# MS SQL Server fails to start after disabling SSL V3 protocol

Tags: sql-server, ssl

I had to disable SSL V3 to avoid poodle attack, but now sql server fails to start. Does Sql Server use SSL V3? If it does - Is there a work around, because my company is forcing me to disable this protocol on the server. My server is MS Server 2008 R2 Standard, and I am using MS Sql Server 2008 Express. I already have other SSL protocols enabled on the server - TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. I have tried searching the web but no luck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: talk to your company's sql server and security experts....Are you implying that your SQL Server is publicly reachable?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Apart from that, don't follow any advice which recommends to disable SSLv3 ciphers, you have to disable SSLv3 protocol only.

Comment: Hi Mitch, Thank you for the reply. No the sql server is not publicly reachable, however there are some web applications using sql server as their database at the back end. So I need to keep the server running in order to these applications to work, however it fails to start if I disable SSL V3.

Comment: Hi Steffen, Thanks for the reply. I will try to look in to your suggested solution, however I have followed this link to disable the protocol on the server: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm. And sorry about asking this server administration question here, but I have always received the best answers from this forum so I preferred it, as I am also a programmer not a system administrator but sometimes I end up doing some configurations on the servers. Your help is appreciated.